# Build a multi linear regression in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, regression, linear-regression, summary

I am trying to build a multilinear regression model that allows the user to choose independent and dependent variables used in the lm() function. However, there are no errors when I run the app, but the regression summary is not displayed. It seems like I am unable to pass the inputs to the lm() function. Can someone point out where I have gone wrong? I really appreciate any help you can provide.
Below is the code

```html
library(shiny)
covid <- read.csv("D:/R/EuropeIndia.csv")
# Define UI for application 
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Regression Analysis for COVID Vaccinations data"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("Select input for Independent variables"),
      selectInput(inputId = "indvar", label = "Independent Variable", multiple = TRUE,
                  choices = list("total_cases","new_cases", "total_vaccinations", "people_fully_vaccinated", "total_boosters","stringency_index", "population_density", "aged_65_older","gdp_per_capita","exterme_poverty", "cardiovasc_death_rate", "diabetes_prevalence", "handwashing_facilities", "life_expectancy","human_development_index")),
      helpText("Select input for dependent variables"),
      selectInput(inputId = "depvar", label = "Dependent variable", multiple = FALSE,
                  choices = list("total_deaths","new_deaths","new_cases"))
    ),
    mainPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "regsum"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "indprint"),
      verbatimTextOutput(outputId = "depprint")
    )
  )
  
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  lm1 <- reactive({lm(reformulate(input$indvar, input$depvar), data = covid)})
  
  output$depPrint <- renderPrint({input$depVar})
  output$indPrint <- renderPrint({input$indVar})
  output$regsum <- renderPrint({summary(lm1())})
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: We don't have access to your D drive, so your code is not reproducible.

Comment: And you have *numerous* inconsistencies in your references to input widgets - eg `regsum` and `regSum`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out inconsistencies the app actually works when I edited them